# How to prove whether $a_{n} = \binom{2n}{n}$ converges to a limit without finding the limit itself?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $a_{n} = \binom{2n}{n}$ and I need to check whether this sequence converges to a limit without finding the limit itself. Now I tried to calculate $a_{n+1}$ but it doesn't get me anywhere. I think I can show somehow that $a_{n}$ is always increasing and that it has no upper bound, but I'm not sure if that's the right way

Comment: You know that the elements of the sequence are integers, so if you can show that it is always (strictly) increasing, then it _must_ grow without bound.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if $n \ge 1$ then $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{(n+1)(n+1)}=2\frac{(2n+1)}{n+1} >2$$

The series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** For $n \ge 1$ we always have $\binom{2n}{n} > n$.

Comment: +1. A combinatorial proof of the inequality: Let $A$ be a set of size $2n$. Fix a set $B \subset A$ of size $n-1$, then there are $n+1$ sets of the form $B \cup \{x\}$.

Comment: @Henrik: Or just note that the sets $\{k,k+1,\ldots,k+n-1\}$ for $k=1,\ldots,n+1$ are $n+1$ distinct subsets of $[2n]$ of cardinality $n$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In case OP asked for further hints, that would've been my goto response.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n$-set $A\subset[2n]$ we can form two different $(n+1)$-sets $$A':=A\cup\{2n+1\},\ A'':=A\cup\{2n+2\}\quad\subset [2(n+1)]\ .$$This implies ${2(n+1)\choose n+1}\geq 2{2n\choose n}$, hence $a_n\to\infty$ $(n\to\infty)$.